# Impedance in AC circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, vectors, capacitance, inductance

why in series $LCR$ circuit impedance is calculated by vector method even though resistance is a scalar quantity.
They should have been added algebraically but instead have been added vectorially

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The current and voltage across an inductor or capacitor are out of phase in an AC circuit and thus vectors can be used to model their impedance.  Look up "ELI the ICE man" mnemonic on the web.  The current and voltage across a resistor are in phase.  Sometimes, complex numbers are used to model AC circuits.